# std::string capacity size

Tags: c++, string, size

Is the capacity size of string always a multiple value of 15?

for example: In all cases the capacity is 15

```
string s1 = "Hello";

string s2 = "Hi";

string s3 = "Hey";
```

or is it random?

Comment: It'll depend on your STL implementation - which compiler version / STL are you using?

Comment: FYI, A quick look at the STL code on VS2008 shows the initial size is 16; maybe the size is implementation specific, but I think there's always an initial capacity bigger than zero.

Comment: I'm on VS2005 VC++ 8.0 but recently I have updated to latest Windows SDK.

Comment: @Max: it's probably saving 1 for the ending \0 .

Comment: A good reference on this topic: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/17-3-stdstring-length-and-capacity/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is the capacity size of string always a multiple value of 15?

No; the only guarantee about the capacity of a `std::string` is that `s.capacity() >= s.size()`.

A good implementation will probably grow the capacity exponentially so that it doubles in size each time a reallocation of the underlying array is required.  This is required for `std::vector` so that `push_back` can have amortized constant time complexity, but there is no such requirement for `std::string`.

In addition, a `std::string` implementation can perform small string optimizations where strings smaller than some number of characters are stored in the `std::string` object itself, not in a dynamically allocated array.  This is useful because many strings are short and dynamic allocation can be expensive.  Usually a small string optimization is performed if the number of bytes required to store the string is smaller than the number of bytes required to store the pointers into a dynamically allocated buffer.

Whether or not your particular implementation performs small string optimizations, I don't know.

Comment: How can i find the std::string implementation detail?

Comment: @user3234: Find your implementation's `<string>` header and take a look.  Is there a particular reason that you need to know or are you just curious?

Comment: I don't see anything in `<string>` header file. I need to append a character `\n` at the end of my std::string but I want to be sure that it doesn't need reallocation Or otherwise I can allocate memory on heap without needing std::string.

Comment: @user3234: `std::string` has a `reserve` member function that behaves just as `std::vector::resize` does. If you need to append another character but `size() == capacity()`, there's really no way around a reallocation.

Answer (score 4):

Implementation specific - std::String usually allocates a small starting string, 16bytes is common.
It's a compromise between not having to do a realloc and move for very short strings and not wasting space

Answer (score 0):

It's an implementation detail on which you're not supposed to rely on; to see exactly how `std::string` grow in your implementation you can have a look at the sources of its CRT. In general it has an exponential grow.